# How to build a powerful home made telescope

Tags: telescope

Simple, I fell in love with the sky when my parents were constructing our new house I was a kid then and one day I ventured out on the terrace, to my amazement it was a full moon, ever since I've felt spiritually connected with the Universe. Its been around 20 years since that day, out of my busy schedule I looked at the stars yesterday, I found love again! Wanted to buy the best telescope out there, but its out of my pocket.

Want to build a home made powerful telescope? Any help fellow sky lovers and star chasers?

Comment: It would not be possible to actually answer how to build a powerful telescope in this type of Q&A. I would suggest doing a bit of research to get started and ask questions about specific problems you may encounter.

Answer (score 3):

You can buy remarkably cheap reflecting telescopes these days on a mount called the Dobsonian mount. They don't (usually) have fancy GoTo automated pointing and tracking, but give fantastic bang for buck as the majority of their cost is invested into the biggest primary mirror possible.

Building a telescope would be a great hobby and learning experience, and there are [many books](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0943396557) which will show you how. Just don't expect to save a significant sum of money over a commercially built scope - [it could even be more expensive to build your own](http://www.garyseronik.com/?q=node/211).

Fancy GoTo tracking mounts are not usually worth the expense and hassle (in setting them up) for a first-timer, though the Orion Intelliscope series is an intriguing compromise. For an extra $100 or so, the telescope has no guiding motors, but tracks where you push the telescope and a hand controller will tell you how much further you have to go till you reach your target.

My recommendation? Get the biggest Dobsonian mount scope you can afford. With a mirror greater than 10" things begin to get large and unwieldy, so 10 inches (mirror diameter, not tube length) is my recommended maximum size for a first telescope. Just go for the biggest aperture you can buy and easily carry. Don't invest much in GoTo systems, as although they can be quite useful they are also a pain to set up if you don't have the scope permanently mounted.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable words, Also to consider that I live in a polluted city..